# Play framework 2.5 sending email

Tags: java, email, playframework, gmail

I'm trying to send email from my play app. I am using [play-mailer plugin](https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer)
I've done all instructions, but still can't connect to gmail

application.conf

```
  play.mailer {

  debug = true
  host = smtp.gmail.com
  port = 465
  ssl = true
  ttl = false
  user = "to******f@gmail.com"
  password = "T****in"
}
```

sending task

```
public static void sendSignUpMsg(MailerClient mailerClient, String verificationLink) {

Email email = new Email()
        .setSubject("Simple email")
        .setFrom("t***f@gmail.com")
        .addTo("d****i@gmail.com")
        .setBodyText("A text message");
mailerClient.send(email);
}
```

so i've got exception

```
     play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[CompletionException: org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:465]]
        at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:280)
        at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:206)
        at play.api.GlobalSettings$class.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:160)
        at play.api.DefaultGlobal$.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:188)
        at play.api.http.GlobalSettingsHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:98)
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:100)
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:99)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:344)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:343)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:465
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:292)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:593)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:577)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1977)
        at scala.concurrent.java8.FuturesConvertersImpl$CF.apply(FutureConvertersImpl.scala:21)
        at scala.concurrent.java8.FuturesConvertersImpl$CF.apply(FutureConvertersImpl.scala:18)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
        at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.processBatch$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:63)
    Caused by: org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:465
        at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1421)
        at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1448)
        at play.api.libs.mailer.SMTPMailer$$anon$2.send(MailerPlugin.scala:100)
        at play.api.libs.mailer.CommonsMailer.send(MailerPlugin.scala:130)
        at play.api.libs.mailer.SMTPMailer.send(MailerPlugin.scala:110)
        at play.api.libs.mailer.SMTPDynamicMailer.send(MailerPlugin.scala:117)
        at play.api.libs.mailer.MailerClient$class.send(MailerPlugin.scala:56)
        at play.api.libs.mailer.SMTPDynamicMailer.send(MailerPlugin.scala:114)
        at services.EmailService.sendSignUpMsg(EmailService.java:14)
        at services.ValidationService.sendVerificationMail(ValidationService.java:33)
    Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2055)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:697)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:386)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:245)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:194)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:253)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
        at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1411)
        at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1448)
        at play.api.libs.mailer.SMTPMailer$$anon$2.send(MailerPlugin.scala:100)
    Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1509)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1491)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
    Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1491)
    DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.5.2
    DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
    DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
    DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle]}
    DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]}
    DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
    [debug] application - DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
    [debug] application - 

    [debug] application - DEBUG SMTP: need username and password for authentication
    [debug] application - 

    [debug] application - DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
    [debug] application - 

[debug] application - DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 465, isSSL false
[debug] application - 

[error] application -
```

i am testing server on my pc, may it cause this problem?

Comment: You have this in debug [debug] application - DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 465, isSSL false  you can try set ssl true directly in code

Comment: Did you find the solution for your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You might just have a typo.
You need tls instead of ttl

From the github page:

```
play.mailer {
  host (mandatory)
  port (defaults to 25)
  ssl (defaults to no)
  tls (defaults to no)
  user (optional)
  password (optional)
  debug (defaults to no, to take effect you also need to set the log level to "DEBUG" for the application logger)
  timeout (defaults to 60s in milliseconds)
  connectiontimeout (defaults to 60s in milliseconds)
  mock (defaults to no, will only log all the email properties instead of sending an email)
}
```